# What is the shortest way

Tags: php

What are the shortest equivalents to the two following statements which do not generate a notice (when error_reporting is E_ALL):

1. `$foo = empty($row['foo']) ? 42 : $row['foo'];`
2. `$foo = empty($row['foo']) ? null : $row['foo'];`

The variable in `empty()` could be non existent or an empty string.

This has been bugging me for so long. I have been searching for alternatives across the Internet, including SO.

The null coalescing operator does not seem to work:

```
$foo = $bar ?? 42;
var_dump($foo);
```

returns `''`, not `42`.

Are my examples really the shortest form to write it?

Comment: `empty` does not generate a warning.

Answer (score 3):

- The [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (`??`) will only check for either `null` or undefined variables.
- The [shorthand ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (`?:`) will check for [*falsy* values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) but can't handle undefined variables by itself.

Therefore, the only shorter way to write these two lines would be to use a combination of both:

```
$foo = ($row['foo'] ?? null) ?: 42;
```

and:

```
$foo = ($row['foo'] ?? null) ?: null;
```

Whether this is easily readable is debatable, but that should work.

Comment: `$foo = $row['foo'] ?? 42` is valid and easier to understand

Comment: @cbaconnier As mentioned in the question, that will return `''` (empty string) if `$row['foo']` is an empty string itself. Same for `false` or any other falsy value that isn't `null`. OP wants it to evaluate to `42` in these cases.